# Magento 2 Not saving product changes at the backend

Tags: magento2, product, admin

Magento 2 I am trying to change product data - first time it is working fine, when i tried to change same attribute second time it not updating which i selected data

Comment: any error message or any log generated ??

Comment: @RkRathod No,it showing You saved the product. if i change default magento attributes those working fine custom attributes means if create new attribute pawan if i change this attribute it not working

Answer (score 0):

In my case  the product class overrided Magento\Catalog\Model\Product 
and  using

```
 $this->load($this->getId())->getData('My_Custom_Attribute');
```

to get my attribute because `$this->getData('My_Custom_Attribute');` was returning **Null**;

**Reloading the product cause to un-updating the product "using load() function"**

so recheck your plugin and try to disable them 1 by 1

here is my problem: plugin code:

```
$product->load($product->getId()); //Here my main product get overrided
```

Replaced with:

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
```